# XPages validateExpression failing

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a field with a validationExpression (shown below) which should error if the field is empty and a previous radio button has been selected. However, even if I have the radio button "BOM" selected the save continues, but it shouldn't. Any ideas anyone?

```
if (getComponent("radioGroup3").getValue() == "BOM") {
    if (getComponent("OrderDateRequired").getSubmittedValue() == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `validateRequired` validator for checking if the field is empty. Other validators are not run if there is no value. You can use `value` in your code to check for the field value.

Comment: It is only required if a previous radio button "BOM" has been selected else it can be left blank. I can't see how to put that condition in.

Comment: Check the value of "BOM" radio button in your `validateRequired` validator.